# Command Objects in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a command object composed of primitive fields and an object field. How do I bind my form fields to the fields in the object?

I tried doing this but to no avail

```
<form:form commandName="course" method="POST">
     <form:input path="activity.activity"/>
         .
         .
         .
</form:form>
```

I get this error

```
org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: 
      Invalid property 'course' of bean class
```

My Command class is like this

```
public class Course {
    private long id;
    private String owner;
    private String title;
    private List<LearningActivity> activity = new ArrayList<LearningActivity>();

    //getters and setters
}

public class LearningActivity {
private long ID;
private String activity;
    private String link;

    //getters and setters
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your list either needs to be pre-populated with as many LearningActivity objects as you plan to refer to (using activity[0], activity[1], etc.) or it needs to be a lazy list.  A lazy list is a list that will populate itself with empty objects when a given index is referenced.

A comment indicates that you're trying to use Apache Commons LazyList, which ought to work -- are you missing an import directive?  However, as an alternative there is a Spring lazy list implementation called AutoPopulatingList.

Answer (score 2):

Two possible issues here:

1. `activity.activity` is invalid (unless your getters do not correspond to your member variables) because `Course.activity` is a list. You need to address a particular list element - e.g. `activity[0].activity`. You'll also have to make sure it actually exists.
2. Have you configured your FormController correctly? Does it pass `Course` instance to view as it should? Take a look at [Spring MVC tutorial](http://static.springsource.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/part4.html#step4.6) for an example.

If after you've fixed #1 and verified that #2 is done correctly the error doesn't go away, please post more details (FormController mapping / source).

Comment: I tried doing #1 but I get an IndexOutOfBoundsException. I found this tutorial: mattfleming.com/node/134 and tried doing List<LearningActivity> acitivity = LazyList.getList(new List<LearningActivity>()); but I get NoClassDefFoundError: org/mortbay/util/LazyList. I already tried putting the commons-collection.jar in my build path and in my web-inf/lib path but somehow the app still does not find i

Comment: You get `IndexOutOfBounds` because your list is empty. As I said above, you need to make sure that list element actually exists. Why are you using the list to begin with? Are you going to edit multiple activities on a single page? If so, you'll need to iterate over the list. If not, consider exposing current activity as a single-valued property.

Comment: Got this to work! I used the Lazy List in jakarta commons to populate my list. Thanks!