# what is the command object in spring framework

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Could you please explain about **command object in spring frame work with an example**?

Comment: If you Google "command object spring", this very first hit is the Spring documentation which answers this question.

Comment: @AaronSheffey The top hit is now this question.

Comment: Well, my comment was over a year ago...

Answer (score 43, accepted):

*from Spring Documentation:*

- `Command Object` - a JavaBean which will be populated with the data from your forms

Think of `Command Object` as a POJO/JavaBean/etc.. that backs the form in your presentation layer.

Once the form is submitted, all the individual attributes are mapped/bound to this object. On the way up to presentation, `Command Object` properties may be used to pre/populate the form.

check an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1429760/command-objects-in-spring)

Comment: With respect to [Spring MVC's 3.2 documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html), all of the following terms seem to be synonymous: *command object*, *form object*, *form-backing object*

Comment: @Abdull I found this in Spring reference: "Each role -- controller, validator, command object, form object, model object, DispatcherServlet, handler mapping, view resolver, and so on -- can be fulfilled by a specialized object." Looks like they are different

Comment: The command object is logically not the same as the form object, but in practice they are often implemented as one. Form objects offer fields that your webforms store values in, command objects are objects with methods that can be called to get values to show on your website. Example: `<p> It is #{commandObject.getTime()} o'clock right now</p>`