# what is the meaning of commandName and path in spring mvc?

Tags: spring-mvc

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>

<form:form action="LoginFormHyperLink" commandName="loginForm">

User Name:<form:errors path="userName" />

<form:input path="userName" />  

Password:<form:errors path="password" />

<form:password path="password" />       

<input type="submit" value="Submit" />                  

</form:form>
```

What is the exact meaning of form and why do we need it? and also what is this path? What is the exact meaning of form and why do we need it? and also what is this path?
what is the exact meaning of form and why do we need it?? and also what is this path?

Comment: possible duplicate of [what is the command object in spring framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7583577/what-is-the-command-object-in-spring-framework)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

commandName is the name of a variable in the request scope or session scope that contains the information about form,it should be a bean.

Path is the name of a bean property that should be accessed in order to pass the information to form and to the controller.